# Have two background colors in the navbar when the sidebar is shown

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

I have made a simple page which has a `navbar` of `bootstrap` and a sidebar: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kavupixuri/1/edit?html,output). At the moment, the background color of the navbar is `black`.

Now, I want to accomplish the follows:

1) when the page is NOT wide enough to show the sidebar, I want the background color of the navbar to be entirely `black`.

2) Whereas, when the page is wide enough to show the sidebar, I want the area of the navbar **above the sidebar** to have a different background color (eg, `white`). Like the following screenshot, the area above the sidebar is `blue`, while the rest of the navbar is `white`.

I tried to add an element in the navbar with `<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">`, but it did not work. It seems that this can only be contained in `container` or `container-fluid`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Is there any workaround?

[image]

Comment: the collapse nav side bar opens and close on a hamburger icon.. I dont see hamburger icon in your jsbin example. how are you going to open/close the sidebar?

Comment: Please see the JSBin: the open/close the sidebar is totally up to the width of the page. It is not like the screenshot I displayed.

Comment: when width is small I can see the sidebar hides and a hamburger icon appears..

Comment: I see what you mean... the hamburger icon is done by 3 `<span class="icon-bar"></span>`.

Comment: actually your exact requirment is still confusing... How the navbar and sidebar will open/close..

Comment: I want the changing follows totally the opening/closing of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) when the page is NOT wide enough to show the sidebar, I want the
>   background color of the `navbar` to be entirely black.

You can add media query to your body tag just including it after body in css

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
      background-color: #000; // black color for background
    }
  }
```

> 2) Whereas, when the page is wide enough to show the sidebar, I want the area of the navbar above the sidebar to have a different background color (eg, white). Like the following screenshot, the area above the sidebar is blue, while the rest of the `navbar` is white.

You can move your Project Name outside navbar and apply it width and color.

Don't forget to add media query to make rest remain of navbar white :)

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 51px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
      background-color: #F8F8F8; // background color of navbar
      border-color: #E7E7E7; // border color of navbar
    }
  }
```

Part that you need

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="background-color: #428bca; border-color: #E7E7E7;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
```

Full nav-bar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="background-color: #428bca; border-color: #E7E7E7;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gukacimaza/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: I am not sure you understand my question... I want **the area of the navbar above the sidebar** to be different from the rest of the navbar...

Comment: @SoftTimur ye, sorry, misunderstood you. will fix in moment.

Comment: @SoftTimur no problem :) feel free to ask any questions. also you could move this part `style="background-color: #428bca; border-color: #E7E7E7;"` to your style section and add custom name to it